# How to solve svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected, in my case?

Tags: apache, svn, configuration

I know there are other questions that look the same, but I wasn't able to find anything useful for my exact case.

My server's URL is: http://servername.domain.com
My server has ZPanel installed, so the path to this in the server is:
/var/zpanel/hostdata/username/public_html/servername_domain_com/

I created a subfolder "svn", set up SVN to use that folder and created repos inside it, changed the owner etc. Surfing to it works, requires login and then you can see "Revision 0". But when trying to check out or do anything, it will give the error from the title.

I installed SVN and put this as the config.

```
< Location /svn>    
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/zpanel/hostdata/username/public_html/servername_domain_com/svn    
AuthType Basic    
AuthName "Subversion repositories"
AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
Require valid-user
< / Location>
```

Do you have any idea why it isn't working? I didn't change the virtualhosts file, it simply contains the default link for the servername.domain.com.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `/var/zpanel/hostdata/username/public_html/servername_domain_com/` is your `DocumentRoot` (i.e. /svn is physical subdirectory), you have misconfiguration from Apache's side:

**Single path can not be physical directory and logical path, defined as Location, at the same time**

You **must** to move SVNParentPath outside web-space

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did try that too. I made a folder in the root of my server: svn. I changed the SVNParentPath to /svn and the location was still /svn so I could browse http://domain.com/svn and it would show a svn repositories listing in the browser. But whenever trying to checkout or connecting to the repo, I would still get the same error.

Any ideas? :D

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem - on editing httpd.conf I prefer **always** restart Apache manually

Comment: I tried so many things, I guess I forgot to restart it after trying this particular fix! It works now, thanks a lot!